# connection string of RabbitMQ cluster using nodejs?

Tags: rabbitmq, node-amqp

I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ cluster using nodejs library [amqplib](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node)

I cannot find any information on connection string. I am trying var

```
amqp_url = 
 ["amqp://admin:admin@172.26.126.248:5672/vhost_test","amqp://admin:admin@172.26.126.249:5672/vhost_test","amqp://admin:admin@172.26.126.250:5672/vhost_test"];
```

is there any other library supports cluster?

Comment: See examples of how to define the URL here: https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/nodejs.html and here: https://youtu.be/9V8Fbbup-WQ?t=115

Comment: @jrhodin I looked into that document already but I coudn't find anything on connection string for cluster of nodes. Sorry if I am missing something. I will look into video.

Answer (score 1):

What version are you use ?

If you are using version `0.5.0` or earlier, you can use this configuration:

```
const hosts = [
  'rabbitmq-node1:5672',
  'rabbitmq-node2:5672',
  'rabbitmq-node3:5672'
];

const connection = await amqp.connect({
  port: 5672,
  username: 'guest',
  password: 'guest',
  hosts: hosts, // specify the cluster nodes
  heartbeat: 60 // send a health check every 60 seconds to check that the connection is still active
});
```

otherwise if it's a version **higher than 0.5.0**, I think **amqplib** doesn't take into account this ability to specify hosts anymore.
In fact, it should do

```
const amqp_uri = 'amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq-node1:5672';

const connection = await amqp.connect(amqp_uri);
```

and behind it, RabbitMQ provides the other urls of the nodes during the connection.